# SQL 2008 over the internet replication

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

Please excuse me for the (probably) stupid question, but SQL Server is not my main proficiency here...

I have 2 SQL Server 2008 R2 servers, one in an AzureVM and another one in my local datacenter.  The machines are not in the same domain and there is no VPN.  I am trying to set up snapshot replication, so that the Azure SQL sends updates to my local machine every hour.

I have successfully created the Publication on the AzureVM, and I can see the snapshot files in their proper directory.

However, I am having difficulty with the local SQL. These are the steps I have performed so far:

1. Created an alias for the Azure DB in the local DB;
2. Tested connectivity with telnet on port 1433 (OK!);
3. When trying to create a Subscription, I am using SQL Server Authentication to retrieve the Publications, but it fails with the following message (my SQL Server is in Portuguese; apologies for eventual translation errors):

> Network error or specific to the instance when trying to establish connection with SQL Server. Server not found or not accessible. Please check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server allows remote connections (provider: TCP Provider, error:0 - Unknown host) (Microsoft SQL Server: Error: 11001)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you specifying for a hostname? I don't think SQL Server plays nicely with IP addresses as far as I'm aware.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't.  That's why Microsoft instructs you to create an alias as I did in step 1.  Still it doesn't work.

Comment: So I have sorted out the problem... If you create an alias and try to replicate using this alias, you need to place an entry in your `hosts` files as well.